# login returns no user but I have users in database

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I am trying to create a user login system for a website and users can register but when I try to login it shows an error message that there is no user by that email. Not sure what the problem is . Here is the code for login. Help please.
this part is part if index.php

```
<?php 
     if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if (isset($_POST['login'])) { //user logging in
        require 'login.php';        
    }   
    elseif (isset($_POST['register'])) { //user registering        
        require 'register.php';        
    }}
   ?>

    <div id="login" class="col-md-12">
    Login via
        <div class="social-buttons">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-fb"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-tw"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i> </a>
        </div>
        or
     <form  method="post" action="index.php" accept-charset="UTF-8" autocomplete="off">
            <div class="form-group">
                 <label class="sr-only"  for="loginInputEmail">Email address</label>
                 <input type="email" required class="form-control"  id="loginInputEmail" placeholder="Email address" >
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                 <label class="sr-only" for="loginInputPassword">Password</label>
                 <input type="password" required  class="form-control" id="loginInputPassword2" placeholder="Password" >
                 <div class="help-block text-right"><a href="includes/forgot.php">Forgot your password?</a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">

                 <button class="button button-block" name='login' />Log In</button>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
                 <label>
                 <input type="checkbox"> keep me logged-in
                 </label>
            </div>
     </form>
     New here? Join Us

    </div>
    <div id="signup" style="display:none;" class="col-md-12">
    <form method="post" action="index.php" accept-charset="UTF-8" autocomplete="off" >
        <div class="form-group">
             <label class="sr-only" for="regInputFName">First Name</label>
             <input type="text" required class="form-control" name ='firstname' id="regInputFName" placeholder="First Name" >
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
             <label class="sr-only" for="lastName">Last Name</label>
             <input type="lastName" required class="form-control" name='lastname' id="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" >

        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
             <label class="sr-only" for="loginInputEmail">Email address</label>
             <input type="email" required class="form-control" name='email' id="loginInputEmail" placeholder="Email address" >
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
             <label class="sr-only" for="loginInputPassword">Password</label>
             <input type="password" required class="form-control" name='password' id="loginInputPassword2" placeholder="Password" >
             <div class="help-block text-right"><a href="includes/forgot.php">Forgot your password?</a></div>
        </div>
        --<div class="form-group">

            <button type="submit" class="button button-block" name="register" />Register</button> 
        </div>
        Member? Sign in!                
     </form>                                                                        
    </div>              
    </div>
```

and the following code is the login.php

```
<?php
    $email = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['email']);
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'");

if ( $result->num_rows == 0 ){ 
    $_SESSION['message'] = "User with that email doesn't exist!";
    header("location: error.php");
}
else { 
    $user = $result->fetch_assoc();
    if ( password_verify($_POST['password'], $user['password']) ) {        
        $_SESSION['email'] = $user['email'];
        $_SESSION['first_name'] = $user['first_name'];
        $_SESSION['last_name'] = $user['last_name'];
        $_SESSION['active'] = $user['active'];        
        $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
        header("location: profile.php");
    }
    else {
        $_SESSION['message'] = "You have entered wrong password, try again!";
        header("location: error.php");
    }
}
```

And finally the following is the register.php code that that works fine and creates user info in the database in phpmyadmin users database.

```
<?php
$_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
$_SESSION['first_name'] = $_POST['firstname'];
$_SESSION['last_name'] = $_POST['lastname'];

$first_name = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['firstname']);
$last_name = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['lastname']);
$email = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['email']);
$password = $mysqli->escape_string(password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT));
$hash = $mysqli->escape_string( md5( rand(0,1000) ) );

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'") or die($mysqli->error());

if ( $result->num_rows > 0 ) {    
    $_SESSION['message'] = 'User with this email already exists!';
    header("location: error.php");

}
else { 
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, email, password, hash) " 
            . "VALUES ('$first_name','$last_name','$email','$password', '$hash')";

    if ( $mysqli->query($sql) ){
        $_SESSION['active'] = 0; //0 until user activates their account with verify.php
        $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true; // So we know the user has logged in
        $_SESSION['message'] =                
                 "Confirmation link has been sent to $email, please verify
                 your account by clicking on the link in the message!";

        $to      = $email;
        $subject = 'Account Verification ';
        $message_body = '
        Hello '.$first_name.',
        Thank you for signing up!
        Please click this link to activate your account:
        http://localhost/login-system/verify.php?email='.$email.'&hash='.$hash;  
        mail( $to, $subject, $message_body );
        header("location: profile.php"); 
    }

    else {
        $_SESSION['message'] = 'Registration failed!';
        header("location: error.php");
    }
}
```

I appreciate any help to fix the problem with loging in and the data is there in myphpmydmin.

Comment: Your login inputs are missing the `name` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made two mistakes. In `login.php`, you are reading POST values `email` and `password`, but the controls in the `index.php`, in the form, have the id `loginInputEmail`, respectively `loginInputPassword2`. So, in `login.php`, replace:

```
$email = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['email']);
```

with this:

```
$email = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['loginInputEmail']);
```

and this:

```
if ( password_verify($_POST['password'], $user['password']) ) {
```

with this:

```
if ( password_verify($_POST['loginInputPassword2'], $user['password']) ) {
```

### EDIT:

Yes, now I tested and... big surprise: the values of the inputs having only id attributes defined are still not recognized. So, I gave you a false answer. The right one would be to define "name=email" and "name=password" for the inputs in the login form in index.php.

Comment: Bingo! Thanks a lot for your help. the edited part got it working. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I am not sure where the down vote came from, I did not do it. You gave me the right answer.

Comment: @Asfawz I'm glad it worked for you. No no, I know you didn't downvoted my answer. Someone did it in the first 3 seconds after I posted. A world record :-) But that downvote made me make my tests and reedit my answer with the right test results.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is ok.. you have missed name attribute in login form section

example code,

See that your code

```
 <input type="email" required class="form-control"  id="loginInputEmail" placeholder="Email address" >
```

Correct code should

```
  <input type="email" required class="form-control"  id="loginInputEmail" placeholder="Email address" name="email" >
```

Comment: You are right that I needed the name attribute but it had to be on both the email and password inputs. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Asfawz , hah ha.  it's not mistake i had implemet that is 'example code ' in top of the my answer. good luck

Comment: I am thankful for your help and sorry I did not get the whole information. Cheers!